# Docker-compose mount folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Hi I have multiple folders that I wish to mount. this is the scenario:

On my host:
 path\to\mount\HostFolder\folder_*

On my container:
  \path\to\mount\ContainerFolder\

* is a number

I want to mount all folder_* to ContainerFolder\
ContainerFolder already have some folders inside so I must not mount HostFolder to ContainerFolder to save them.

I wish to use regex but *volume* keyword doesn't seems to support it, any suggestions how to manage that?

My only idea right now is script to write for me the docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to seriously reconsider the assumption that you *need* the current directory structure. (Of course, this may be impossible, I know.)

If you can change the directory structure at all, you can try restructuring the folders like this:

- ContainerFolder

  - folders

    - folder_1
    - folder_2

In this way, you can mount the HostFolder into a subdirectory of ContainerFolder without overwriting the contents of ContainerFolder itself.